# Setting preference color Android

Tags: android, android-layout

SettingFragment.java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceFragment;

public class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.prefs);

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        // getView().setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        // getView().setClickable(true);
    }
}
```

style.xml

```
<resources>

<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"></style>

<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="android:textAppearanceLarge">@style/MyTextAppearance</item>
</style>

<style name="PrefsTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/black</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:listViewStyle">@style/listViewPrefs</item>
</style>

<style name="listViewPrefs" parent="@android:style/Widget.ListView">
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/black</item>
    <item name="android:cacheColorHint">@android:color/darker_gray</item>
</style>
```

Manifest

```
 <activity
            android:name="com.androidass.doubleclickflash.SettingsFragment"
            android:theme="@style/PrefsTheme"
            android:title="Settings" />
```

After all this, my settings is still white transparent, But i can able to remove the transparency by un-commenting `getView().setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);` in SettingFragment.java but i cant able to change the style of SettingFragment to dark. Its not at all taking `android:theme="@style/PrefsTheme"`. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem but found i didn't need to do all the style.xml stuff. Remove your style themes and the reference in manifest.  Just go straight to your SettingsFragment.java and replace your two commented getView() statements with one of the following:

`

```
    // set it as a drawable
    getView().setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_drawable_resource);

    // or set it as a colour (one or the other, probably not worth doing both)
    getView().setBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY);
```

`